# Login with Facebook from android works only once

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

While using facebook sdk to log in with facebook, the app runs well in the development mode but while using the signed apk, log in buttton is working well for the first time use and to log in for the next time I have to remove the app from the facebook apps and games i.e. if the app is not listed in the saved facebook apps and games then log in works well but once I give the permission for the app in facebook I can't log in again.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                emailid = object.getString("email");
                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                String name = object.getString("name");

                                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("email", emailid).commit();
                                fb_signup(name, emailid);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: did u add logout code when logged in?

Comment: yes.....using this method
    public void method_signOut(View v){
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!= null ){
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }

Comment: and there aren't any issues while working in development mode

Comment: did u properly set the release hash key in developer panel? also in your developer panel u need to make the app live.

Comment: yes the app is live and hash key is also correct as it is working well in release mode for the first time or every time I remove the app from the facebook apps and games.